# Iterator applying to a HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, iterator

So I tend to look over open source code a lot, and in a lot of code I see something like this

```
HashMap<Player, Set<Integer>> tracker = new WeakHashMap<>();
public void Example() {
Iterator i = tracker;
i.SomeMethodTheMapCanDo;
}
```

but, when I do code like that I always get a compiler error, but yet I keep on seeing it, and it works. 
Is this just the JDK/IDE giving a wrong error or is a thing with older Javas.

Comment: Wich error do you have?

Comment: Found: java.util.Map
Needed: java.util.Iterator

Comment: Can you post the code you use, please ?

Comment: Well, tracker is of type Map, and you're trying to assign it to a variable of type Iterator. Since a Map is not an Iterator, that can't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
Iterator i = tracker;
```

Map does not implement Iterator.

If you want an Iterator from a Map, first you need to decide whether you want the keySet(), entrySet(), or the values() iterator.

For example:

```
    Iterator<? extends Map.Entry<?, ?>> i = tracker.entrySet().iterator();
    i.forEachRemaining(entry -> {
        System.out.format("Key: %s, Value: %s%n",
                entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    });
```

Comment: I realize that, but why then whenever I decide to look over old code from like Java 6-7 do I see that kind of statement all the time?